# Even after setting environmental variables getting: 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: maven

```
> C:\Users\jt_soc>mvn -version 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or
> external command, operable program or batch file.
> 
> C:\Users\jt_soc>echo %M2_HOME% C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.1
> 
> C:\Users\jt_soc>echo %M2% C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.9.1\bin
> 
> C:\Users\jt_soc>echo %maven_opts% Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

I have already set the environmental variables. And it is getting reflected in cmd. But still I'm getting mvn not recognized error.

Comment: Maven must be on the PATH variable. After setting the PATH, you need to restart the cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to invoke `mvn` from the command-line. This means that you are trying to instruct `cmd` to invoke a command called `mvn`.  However, `cmd` does not know what these environment variables are for. It has no use for them.

The environment variable that you have to set so that `cmd` can find `mvn` is the `PATH` environment variable.

You can go to "Settings" and search for "environment variables" and from there you can go to "Edit environment variables for your account" and then add an entry with the full path to `mvn.exe`, or you can execute `set PATH=%PATH%;full-path-to-mvn.exe`